# Ordered semirings s.t. $A > AB$ iff $A \neq 0$ and $B = 0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, order-theory, semiring

I've found an algorithm that only seems to make sense in the case of ordered semirings such that $A > AB$ iff $A \neq 0$ and $B = 0$. Is there a name for (semirings with) such an ordering? The property holds for the natural numbers, but not for number sets having $0 \neq n < 1$.